# Nginx facing problem when proxy_pass contains undersocres

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx server which redirect requests to another external sites.
The location configuration below :

> ```
> location ~* ^\/h\/([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\/(.*) {
>
>         proxy_connect_timeout 20s;
>         set $remote_host $1;
>         proxy_set_header Host $remote_host;
>         proxy_pass http://$remote_host/$2;
> ```

So , the server receive a request like :

> http://localhost/h/test.com/testinguri.txt

and the proxy pass will be  http://test.com/testinguri.txt

Everything works fine until we use two underscores and the server will respond with 502 :

> curl -I http://localhost/h/test.com/testing_ur_i.txt

> HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
> Server: nginx/1.10.3
> Content-Type: text/html
> Content-Length: 173
> Connection: keep-alive

The error log with debug mode :

> 2020/11/05 00:00:11 [error] 40859#40859: *66328156 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ****, server: _, request: "GET /h/test.com/testing_ur_i.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream:

The request failed after least than one second , so it is not a timeout problem. And the distant site works correctly. (i changed the real domain name by test.com for security reasons)

Thank you

Comment: How do you check that the distant site works ? By fetching "http://distant.com/testing_ur_i.txt" ?

Answer (score 1):

Given error actually says that connection was closed by your backend (test.com in your example).

Please try to add it to your location section:

```
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
```

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout

Answer (score 0):

So , it wasn't related to the use of underscore.
The problem was the http version supported by the distant site!

Changing the http to 1.1 for the proxy-pass fixed the issue :

> proxy_http_version 1.1;

Thank you.